# How do i copy the failed upload attempt files?

Tags: php, upload

I have a simple form where in I upload files . When I try to upload large files and if it fails . How do I access the temporary files in php ?

is_uploaded_file and move_uploaded_file only work after the file is completely uploaded.

I am  a looking for a solution based in PHP.

Cheers

Comment: AFAIK, failed uploads are removed at least from `$_FILES` and possible `/tmp`. If the upload fails, then the temporary file will be crap, so there's no point accessing it.

Comment: no if the user has paused it or stopped it

Comment: File Name: **$_FILES['field_name']['name']**  Temporary Name: **$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']**  Size : **$_FILES['field_name']['size']**

Comment: If a large file upload fails due to the web server's or PHP maximum limit on file sizes, there is no way to get hold of the uploaded file. By definition.

Answer (score 4):

I could never reproduce this. The PHP upload code is likely to [purge failed upload files](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/rfc1867.c#L1076). If it doesn't, then the file would just show up in the `$_FILES` array with an [error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) in `[error]`:

```
Array
(
    [name] => community.304.flv
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 3
    [size] => 0
)
```

That would be `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`. In my tests the `tmp_name` however was empty then. So the upload code in the PHP core already unlinks the temporary upload file. And there is no way to bring it back in PHP userland.

Btw, [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) would have failed anyway when the `[error]` is set, even if the temp file was still present. You'd have to use [`copy`](http://php.net/copy) or [`rename`](http://php.net/rename) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>`